# Creating new world

Tags: creature-design, worldbuilding-resources

I'm not very talented in painting. I'm looking for an app or website where I can create my fantasy planet, a uniform or a plant.  Are there any?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE! I do think this is on-topic, but I also think it should be three separate questions - one asking for planet design resources (which I think would be a duplicate anyway tbh), one asking for uniform design resources (and you'll need to specify what *kind* of uniform you're talking about), and one asking for plant design resources.

Comment: You should check-our our list of [worldbuilding resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/143606/a-list-of-worldbuilding-resources), there's plenty of stuff there to keep you busy for a while including mapping software, stuff relating to apparel, flora and fauna creation.

Comment: The [tag:worldbuilding-resources] tag has been around since 2014 and has 150+ questions *just like this one.* And yet two of the close voters voted to close as "not about worldbuilding as defined in the Help Center." Are you people kidding me? I get the "needs more focus" votes, but at worst this would be closed as a duplicate of one of those 150+ other valid and accepted questions. We're here to help, right?

Comment: Agree with @JoinJBHonCodidact that the question is valid as it refers to Worldbuilding but it definitely needs more focus. As is, it's way too broad and undetailed

Answer (score 1):

My glib answer is that you just start writing in details of geography, clothing, and vegetation as you need them to support the story you are telling .. once you have a few chapters written take a pause and review it all with a view to making the freshly invented details that you cobbled up on the fly hang together .. that process will create your backstory and give you a framework to write the rest of it in.

The sources for my artist daughter are

1. YouTube videos by artists who are teaching illustration, water colours, and any other artistic skill you want to learn.
2. Books .. so many books teach art skills
3. teaching tutorials that come with the various drawing and painting tools

I recommend Blender, xxx, and EazyDraw on Mac OS X. On Windows my daughter really likes [Krita](https://krita.org/en/) for her work as an illustrator.

Humm thinking a bit further .. you could use a [free copy of Maya](https://www.autodesk.com/products/maya/free-trial), a 3D modelling and animation tools by AutoCAD .. it is a bit top end but the free version is fully functional and includes a particle generator that can be used to create greenery from grass to jungle giant trees. And then there is the cloth simulation engine for developing clothing. And take a look at Terraray application for creating terrain on a polygonal format that can be imported into most 3D modelling apps.

and don't ignore the linked answer that provides a long list of other resources

Comment: If any of these or any other resources you're aware of are not yet listed on our [page of worldbuilding resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/143606/a-list-of-worldbuilding-resources), please edit the community-wiki answer and add them! We're always looking for more tools to help people build their worlds. Thanks!